# Play Video with GStreamer and wxPanel

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, gstreamer

I'm learning GStreamer and its fun, but I have hit a wall in using it with wxWidgets. No matter what I try I cannot break through. Examples out there are GTK/Qt which are helpful only to some limits. Here is Current code (which does not work) and below it error messages I get

```
wxGStreamer::wxGStreamer(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID winid, const wxURI& location):wxPanel(parent, winid)
{
    SetBackgroundColour(*wxBLACK);

    /* Build the pipeline */
    wxString uri = location.BuildURI();
    wxPuts(uri);

    // prepare the pipeline
    GstElement *pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("xvoverlay");
    GstElement *src = gst_element_factory_make("videotestsrc", NULL);
    GstElement *sink = gst_element_factory_make("xvimagesink", NULL);
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), src, sink, NULL);
    gst_element_link(src, sink);

    /* Set the URI to play */
    g_object_set (pipeline, "uri", "http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm", NULL);

    GtkWidget* widget = GetHandle(); 
    guintptr video_window_handle = GDK_WINDOW_XID (gtk_widget_get_window (widget)); 
    gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(sink), video_window_handle); 

    // run the pipeline
    GstStateChangeReturn sret = gst_element_set_state(pipeline,
                                GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    if(sret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
    {
        gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
    }

    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);
}
```

where wxGStreamer is defined as

```
class  wxGStreamer : public wxPanel {............};
```

Errors
[image: Error Messages]

Comment: I have no experience with GStreamer, but the first error message up there, `assertion 'gst_is_initialized ()' failed`, seems to indicate that `gst_init()` (or `gst_init_check()`) hasn't been called yet. Where are you calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add sync handler using [gst_bus_set_sync_handler](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstBus.html#gst-bus-set-sync-handler) and then inside that function use GstVideoOverlay to channel video to your widget. Here is a working sample function.

```
static GstBusSyncReply
bus_sync(GstBus* bus, GstMessage* message, gpointer user_data)
{
    CustomData* data = reinterpret_cast<CustomData*>(user_data);        

    if(!gst_is_video_overlay_prepare_window_handle_message(message))
        return GST_BUS_PASS;            
    else
    {
        if(data->xid!=NULL)
        {

            GstVideoOverlay *overlay;
            overlay = GST_VIDEO_OVERLAY(GST_MESSAGE_SRC(message));
            gst_video_overlay_set_window_handle(overlay, data->xid);
        }

        return GST_BUS_DROP;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even if you don't want to just use it (why?), at least have a look at what `wxMediaCtrl`, which is implemented using GStreamer under Unix, does.

Comment: I want to use Gstreamer on both Linux and Windows (MediaCtrl uses something else on windows). I searched for its backend files for ages and didn't found. This morning I found it in unix folder (thought will be in gtk)
I think it will be good to have Gst in windows too!